# Creating external JS page to build google charts with dynamic number of and types of charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to use the google chart api to display a number of charts.  The number of charts is dynamic as is the chart type.  Currently, I am only using the pie chart type but will be adding to it.

The page is loaded and the number/type of charts (widgets in code) looks like this:

```
<script>
var widgets = {};
// Load Charts and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
// Draw the pie chart and bar chart when Charts is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(buildWidgets);

$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/api/getPageWidgets.jsp',
    data: {method:''
        , id: <%=custPage%>
        // , viewSampleId: <%=custSurveyId%>
            },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(result){
        widgets = result.widgets;
    } 
});     
$(function(){
    buildWidgets(widgets);
});
</script>
```

In an external JS **(widget.js)** file I have a function that loops through all the widgets and calls a function to `build{charttype}Chart` the function that builds the pie charts is:

```
function buildPieChart(data){
var chartId = "chart-"+data.id
// google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var ib = '<div id="'+chartId+'" class=" col-'+data.layout.w+'">';
var rd = getChartData(data.subType,data.dataConfig)
// console.log(rd);
$("#widget-holder").append(ib);


var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(chartId));
  chart.draw(rd, {width: 400, height: 240});

}
```

but I am obviously not loading the google stuff correctly because I am getting this error:

[image]

I am converting this from the code that was being used when only one chart per page was possible and all of the code was on the initially loaded jsp page.

Since the number and types of the charts are unknown what is the correct way to load the google visualizations. So that they will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

part of your issue is timing,
the ajax call is running before google charts has finished loading.

recommend loading google charts first,
it only needs to be loaded once per page load,
then you can draw as many charts as needed.

once google has loaded, make your ajax call.
also, `async: false` on ajax has been deprecated, use the `done` callback instead.

once ajax is done, continue with `buildWidgets`.

recommend following setup...

```
<script>
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/api/getPageWidgets.jsp',
    data: {method:'',
      id: <%=custPage%>,
      //viewSampleId: <%=custSurveyId%>
    },
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function (result) {
    buildWidgets(result.widgets);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I knew I was doing something simple wrong. Thank you